# Detecting Byte-Range requests in .NET HttpHandler

Tags: .net, http, httphandler

I have a HttpHandler which will do some checks on the incoming requests and in certain cases perform some function.  One of the conditions that needs to be checked is whether the request is a [byte-range request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving).  How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look for a `Range` header in the `Request` object that's part of the `HttpContext` passed to your `ProcessRequest` method.  There is no `Range` property in the `HttpRequest` class, so you'll have to look in the `Headers`.  If there is a `Range` it will be of the form:

`Range: bytes=<start>-<end>`

Where `<start>` and `<end>` are integers.  For example, if somebody wanted 64K from the middle of a file:

`Range: bytes=32768-98304`

You'll have to parse the text into numbers and handle accordingly.

Comment: Good answer.  For the sake of future generations, a little sample code would be nice.  Once I implement it, I hope you don't mind if I inject it into your answer.

Comment: @Larsenal: I didn't supply sample code because I don't have any. I remember working with this some years ago, but the code is long gone.  Hopefully my short description is enough to get you started.  I don't mind if you inject code into my answer.

Comment: FWIW, this lead to me to find the following post with code showing how to handle the ranged request: http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/easy-handling-of-http-range-requests-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 4):

Note that the Range header syntax also allows for things like "0-500, 100-1500" (multiple ranges) and "-500" (last 500 bytes). See RFC 2616 for the gory details, which are too long to quote here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the blog post linked to above in the comment by @brent-keller—which in turn references a [CodePlex entry](http://videostreamer.codeplex.com/)—I came up with the edits below. It's tested with FDM (available [here](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org)). MultiRange requests are not supported (yet). No `Web.config` entries are required.

The original method at CodePlex contains an error—the `Accept-Ranges` header should have a value of simply `bytes`, not the byte range to be returned. That belongs to the `Content-Range` header. The download still works, but you won't get [byte serving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) if you make that mistake.

This modified version is refactored for brevity and readability. It also has the advantage that the file returned isn't necessarily tied to the actual URL—in fact the handler may be called directly from the browser and with query string arguments if need be. This enables dynamic file/data creation and response.

Hopefully someone can do some good with it.

**HTTP Handler**

```
Public Class Upload
  Implements IHttpHandler

  Public Sub ProcessRequest(Context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim oFile As FileInfo

    oFile = New FileInfo(Context.Server.MapPath("~/0HCJ0LE.zip"))

    Me.UploadRange(Context, oFile)
  End Sub



  Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
      Return False
    End Get
  End Property



  Private Sub UploadRange(Context As HttpContext, File As FileInfo)
    Dim oResponse As Response
    Dim oRequest As Request

    Dim _
      nOffset,
      nLength As Long

    Using oReader As New StreamReader(File.FullName)
      Context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")

      oResponse = New Response(oReader)
      oRequest = New Request(oResponse, Context)

      If oRequest.HasRange Then
        If oRequest.IsMultiRange Then
          ' At the moment we only support single ranges.'
          '         * Multiple range support requires some more work'
          '         * to comply with the specifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2'
          '         *'
          '         * Multirange content must be sent with multipart/byteranges mediatype,'
          '         * (mediatype = mimetype)'
          '         * as well as a boundary header to indicate the various chunks of data.'
          ' '        
          ' (?) Shoud this be issued here, or should the first'
          ' range be used? Or should the header be ignored and'
          ' we output the whole content?'
          Me.ThrowBadRange(Context, oResponse)
        Else
          If oRequest.IsBadRange Then
            Me.ThrowBadRange(Context, oResponse)
          Else
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 206

            oResponse.Start = oRequest.Start
            oResponse.End = oRequest.End

            nOffset = oReader.BaseStream.Seek(oResponse.Start, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            nLength = oResponse.End - oResponse.Start + 1
          End If
        End If
      Else
        nOffset = 0
        nLength = oResponse.Size
      End If
    End Using

    Context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip
    Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={File.Name}")
    Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", nLength)
    Context.Response.AddHeader(oResponse.HeaderName, oResponse.HeaderValue)
    Context.Response.WriteFile(File.FullName, nOffset, nLength)
    Context.Response.End()
  End Sub



  Private Sub ThrowBadRange(Context As HttpContext, Response As Response)
    Context.Response.AddHeader(Response.HeaderName, Response.HeaderValue)
    Throw New HttpException(416, "Requested range not satisfiable")
  End Sub
End Class
```

**Range Request**

```
Friend NotInheritable Class Request
  Public Sub New(Response As Response, Context As HttpContext)
    Me.Response = Response
    Me.Context = Context
  End Sub



  Public ReadOnly Property Start As Long
    Get
      If Me.Range(0) = String.Empty Then
        Start = Me.Response.Size - Me.Range(1)
      Else
        Start = Me.Range(0)
      End If
    End Get
  End Property



  Public ReadOnly Property [End] As Long
    Get
      If Me.Range(0) = String.Empty Then
        [End] = Me.Response.End
      Else
        If Long.TryParse(Me.Range(1), 0) Then
          [End] = Me.Range(1)
        Else
          [End] = Me.Response.Size
        End If
      End If

      [End] = Math.Min(Me.Response.End, [End])
    End Get
  End Property



  Public ReadOnly Property HasRange As Boolean
    Get
      Return String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Context.Request.ServerVariables(HTTP_RANGE)) = False
    End Get
  End Property



  Public ReadOnly Property IsMultiRange As Boolean
    Get
      Return Me.Context.Request.ServerVariables(HTTP_RANGE).Contains(",")
    End Get
  End Property



  Public ReadOnly Property IsBadRange As Boolean
    Get
      Return Me.Start > Me.End OrElse Me.Start > Me.Response.Size - 1 OrElse Me.End >= Me.Response.Size
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Property Range As List(Of String)
    Get
      Return Me.Context.Request.ServerVariables(HTTP_RANGE).Split("=")(1).Split("-").ToList
    End Get
  End Property



  Private ReadOnly Response As Response
  Private ReadOnly Context As HttpContext

  Private Const HTTP_RANGE As String = "HTTP_RANGE"
End Class
```

**Range Response**

```
Friend NotInheritable Class Response
  Public Sub New(Reader As StreamReader)
    _Size = Reader.BaseStream.Length
    Me.End = Me.Size - 1
  End Sub



  Public Property Start As Long
  Public Property [End] As Long
  Public ReadOnly Property Size As Long



  Public ReadOnly Property HeaderName As String
    Get
      Return "Content-Range"
    End Get
  End Property



  Public ReadOnly Property HeaderValue() As String
    Get
      Return $"bytes {Me.Start}-{Me.End}/{Me.Size}"
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```